# Creating text prompts with jquery Terminal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I've read the docs and the article on jquery Terminal

https://itnext.io/how-to-create-interactive-terminal-like-website-888bb0972288

I'm using it for the GUI basically and not so much for the command line terminal properties.
I just want to be able to use it for question/answer. So essentially to echo out a question and then read in an answer. A bit like those games that used to give options and then you would decide what to do next.

In the article the code:

```
<script>
$('body').terminal({
    hello: function(what) {
        this.echo('Hello, ' + what +
                  '. Wellcome to this terminal.');
    }
}, {
    greetings: 'My First Web Terminal'
});
</script>
```

Creates a greeting but you would need to know the command 'hello' exists so you could type hello world. And if you type an incorrect command you get an error "Command x not found".

Similarly, the code in the docs for reading in input is:

```
$('#term').terminal({
   name: function(name) {
      this.read('last name: ', last_name => {
         this.echo('Your name is ' + name + ' ' + last_name);
      });
   }
});
```

But you would need to know that the name command exists.

Is there an easy way to just setup a question/answer system without knowing what the commands would be in advance?

Also, didn't quite get the different uses for why you might want to create the interpreter as a function/object/string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call read outside of the terminal:

```js
  const term = $('...').terminal();

  term.read('last name: ', last_name => {
     this.echo('Your name is ' + name + ' ' + last_name);
  });
```

And if you want something more complex you can check the example [Create Settings object from questions](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#questions).